# Fixed 3-level Menu Tree

Tags: mysql

I need a 3-level menu tree (not unlimited)

tablename = LEVEL1

```
+-------------+----------------------+
| level1_id   | name                 |
+-------------+----------------------+
|           1 | AIR CONDITIONER      |
|           2 | TV                   |
+-------------+----------------------+
```

tablename = LEVEL2

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----------+
| level2_id   | name                 | level1_id |
+-------------+----------------------+-----------+
|           1 | SPLIT TYPE           |      1    |
|           2 | WINDOWS TYPE         |      1    |
|           3 | LCD                  |      2    |
|           4 | PLASMA               |      2    |
|           5 | MUSIC PLAYER         |   NULL    |
+-------------+----------------------+-----------+
```

tablename = LEVEL3

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----------+
| level3_id   | name                 | level2_id |
+-------------+----------------------+-----------+
|           1 | AC 0.75 TON          |      1    |
|           2 | AC 1 TON             |      1    |
|           3 | WT 0.75 TON          |      2    |
|           4 | WT 1 TON             |      2    |
|           5 | LCD 32" UP           |      3    |
|           6 | LCD 42" UP           |      3    |
|           7 | PLASMA 32" UP        |      4    |
|           8 | PLASMA 42" UP        |      4    |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      5    |
|          10 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      5    |
|          11 | CDS                  |   NULL    |
|          12 | BOOKS                |   NULL    |
+-------------+----------------------+-----------+
```

Is it possible to run a single mysqli query that gets the following result?
So that I know exactly which level each catagory falls into?

```
+------------------+----------------+-----------------+
| LEVEL1           | LEVEL2         | LEVEL3          |
+------------------+----------------+-----------------+
| AIR CONDITIONER  | SPLIT TYPE     | AC 0.75 TON     |
| AIR CONDITIONER  | SPLIT TYPE     | AC 1 TON        |
| AIR CONDITIONER  | WINDOWS TYPE   | WT 0.75 TON     |
| AIR CONDITIONER  | WINDOWS TYPE   | WT 1 TON        |
| TV               | LCD            | LCD 32" UP      |
| TV               | LCD            | LCD 42" UP      |
| TV               | PLASMA         | PLASMA 32" UP   |
| TV               | PLASMA         | PLASMA 42" UP   |
| NULL             | MUSIC PLAYER   | CD PLAYERS      |
| NULL             | MUSIC PLAYER   | MP3 PLAYERS     |
| NULL             | NULL           | CDS             |
| NULL             | NULL           | BOOKS           |
+------------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

A bit greedier. Can someone help me with this as well which list out all the name/id WHERE parent id IS NULL

```
+------------------+------------+------+
| name             | tablename  |  id  |
+------------------+------------+------+
| AIR CONDITIONER  | LEVEL1     |   1  |
| TV               | LEVEL1     |   2  |
| MUSIC PLAYER     | LEVEL2     |   5  |
| CDS              | LEVEL3     |  11  |
| BOOKS            | LEVEL3     |  12  |
+------------------+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you presented tables Level3 is main table and will always have some data. i suppose the way you are doing fit your needs. however you should try also with two tables, Id, Name, ParentID only one table you can go unlimited relation. where Parentid is higher level id of same table.

Anyway this query should work for your case:

'SELECT LEVEL1.name, LEVEL2.name, LEVEL3.name
FROM (LEVEL1 RIGHT JOIN LEVEL2 ON LEVEL1.level1_id = LEVEL2.level1_id) RIGHT JOIN LEVEL3 ON LEVEL2.level2_id = LEVEL3.level2_id;'

Comment: That works great.

Can you help me with the top menu which I added to the question? Many Thx

Comment: sorry i was not online just saw your question. in which language, Html, C#, PHP because i can help maybe with HTML C#?

Comment: Well, I can do it myself with php script (repeated queries) and just wondering if that can be achieved by using a single mysql query instead coz that would be a lot more efficient. I have modified my question and added the query result expected :)